# Concentration bound for Poisson Binomial distribution

Tags: probability

Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ be the sum of $n$ independent Bernoulli random variables with $E[X_i]=p_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n p_i=\mu$. I would like to bound $\Pr[X>t]$. Of course, the standard Chernoff bound can be used here, however that bound depends only on $\mu$ and so does not distinguish, say, (1) $p_1=\mu$ and $p_i=0$ for $i>1$ from (2) $p_i=\mu/n$ for all $i$. What is a better bound that takes the ${p_i}$ into account?

Comment: You may find something useful [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/253775/poisson-binomial-distribution), BTW, your distribution is called [Poisson Binomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_binomial_distribution).

Comment: There is an exact formula for this tail, $\sum_{I\subseteq [n],|I|\ge t} \prod_{i\in I} p_i$. From there you can estimate things differently depending on the shape of the $p_i$-s